# Android crop image after taken

Tags: android, android-gallery

I am trying to let to user crop images after taking them / choosing from gallery. Now, the cropping after selecting from gallery works but not camera. Below are my codes, I am not getting any error message. We followed http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/capture-and-crop-an-image-with-the-device-camera/

```
//Camera button  clicked
    public void camera_click(View view) {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

    } 
    //Result of camera capture
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                 //camera
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {

                mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
                performCrop();
            }
            if (requestCode == PIC_CROP) {
                //get the returned data
                try{
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
//get the cropped bitmap
                thumbnail = extras.getParcelable("data");
                //retrieve a reference to the ImageView
                ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
//display the returned cropped image
                image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                TextView imgTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageInfo);
                String desc = imgTv.getText().toString();
                if (desc.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    String errorMessage = "Please enter a description before submitting a photo.";
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                } else {

                }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.i("err", ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
                 //gallery selected
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO) {
                if (data != null) {

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(data.getData(), null, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();  //if not doing this, 01-22 19:17:04.564: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26264): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
                    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ImageColumns.DATA);
                    String fileSrc = cursor.getString(idx);
                    thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileSrc); //load preview image
                    thumbnail = android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(thumbnail, 100, 100, true);
                    //   ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
                    // image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                    ImageButton cam = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.camera);
                    //    cam.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    ImageButton gal = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
                    mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
                    //  gal.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    performCrop();

                } else {
                    //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "idButSelPic Photopicker canceled");
                    // m_Tv.setText("Image selection canceled!");
                }

            }
        }
    }//end onactivity results

    //method to luanch crop image
private void performCrop() {
    try {
        //call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not support it)
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");


        cropIntent.setDataAndType(mImageCaptureUri, "image/*");
         //set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        //indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        //indicate output X and Y
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
        //retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        //display an error message
        Log.i("err", anfe.getLocalizedMessage());
        String errorMessage = "Your device doesn't support the crop action!";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent();
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, PIC_CROP);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is probably giving you this problem:

```
mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
```

Delete this and check it out.

If not, I could give you a working code.

**Working sample:**
Include also this library: https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         switch (requestCode) {
            case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:


                    doCrop();



                break;

            case PICK_FROM_FILE: 
                if(data != null){
                mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();

                doCrop();
                }
                break;          

            case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:     
                if(data != null){
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

                if (extras != null) {               
                    Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");

                    imagebutton.setImageBitmap(photo);
                    imagebutton.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);


                }

                File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());            

                if (f.exists()) f.delete();
                }
                break;

        }
    }

    private void doCrop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
//        intent.setClassName("com.android.camera", "com.android.camera.CropImage");
        intent.setType("image/*");

        List<ResolveInfo> list = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0 );

        int size = list.size();

        if (size == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Can not find image crop app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return;
        } else {
            intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);

            intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            intent.putExtra("scale", true);
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

            if (size == 1) {
                Intent i        = new Intent(intent);
                ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

                i.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

                startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
            } else {
                for (ResolveInfo res : list) {
                    final CropOption co = new CropOption();

                    co.title    = getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.icon     = getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.appIntent= new Intent(intent);

                    co.appIntent.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

                    cropOptions.add(co);
                }

                CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(getActivity(), cropOptions);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");
                builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) {
                        startActivityForResult( cropOptions.get(item).appIntent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                    }
                });

                builder.setOnCancelListener( new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel( DialogInterface dialog ) {

                        if (mImageCaptureUri != null ) {
                            getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null, null );
                            mImageCaptureUri = null;
                        }
                    }
                } );

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                alert.show();
            }
        }
    }
```

**CropOption class:**

```
public class CropOption {
    public CharSequence title;
    public Drawable icon;
    public Intent appIntent;
}
```

**CropOptionAdapter:**

```
public class CropOptionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CropOption> {
    private ArrayList<CropOption> mOptions;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CropOptionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CropOption> options) {
        super(context, R.layout.crop_selector, options);

        mOptions    = options;

        mInflater   = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup group) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.crop_selector, null);

        CropOption item = mOptions.get(position);

        if (item != null) {
            ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon)).setImageDrawable(item.icon);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name)).setText(item.title);

            return convertView;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: See if you can understand.

Comment: Can you post the doCrop method as well?

Comment: Thanks for the sample codes. May I know if "CropOption" is an additional class written by you?

Comment: No sorry, its from a crop image library, check out the link in the answer.

Comment: Thete is no CropOption class in the library

Comment: Just added the CropOption class and his adapter